# Large Visual Digit Counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to reuse some code that existed in a theme I used a while back.  I can't seem to get it to work on its own.

It should simply take the value in the HTML and animate the digits like a counter, quickly.

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/96roocq1/5/

or the JS/CSS/HTML below:

```
<div class="counter_holder center" style="color:#ffffff; font-size:168px;">

  <span class="counter type1" data-delay="" style="background-color: black; height:168px; line-height:168px;">1678</span>

</div>
```

---

```
.counter_holder {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity: 0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
}

.counter_holder.left {
  text-align: left;
}

.counter_holder.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.counter_holder.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.counter_holder span.counter {
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block !important;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.counter_holder h4 {
  margin: 30px 0px 0px;
}

.counter_holder p {
  margin: 18px 0px 0px;
}

.tocounter {
  float: none;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

---

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();


function resizeFonts(){
    "use strict";

    if($j(".counter_holder").length){
        $j(".counter_holder").each(function(){
            var $this = $j(this);

            var counterFontSize = $j(this).css("font-size");
            var counterDigitsWidth = $this.find('span.counter').width();

            var resize = function () {
                if($this.width() <= counterDigitsWidth){

                    $this.css('font-size', Math.min($this.width() / (0.3*10), parseFloat(counterFontSize)));
                    $this.css('line-height', Math.min($this.width() / (0.3*10), parseFloat(counterFontSize))+'px');

                    $this.find('span.counter').css('line-height', Math.min($this.width() / (0.3*10), parseFloat(counterFontSize))+'px');
                    $this.find('span.counter').css('height', Math.min($this.width() / (0.3*10), parseFloat(counterFontSize))+'px');
                }else{
                    $this.css('font-size', parseFloat(counterFontSize));
                    $this.css('line-height', parseFloat(counterFontSize)+'px');

                    $this.find('span.counter').css('line-height', parseFloat(counterFontSize)+'px');
                    $this.find('span.counter').css('height', parseFloat(counterFontSize)+'px');
                }
      };

      resize();

      $j(window).on('resize orientationchange', resize);
        });

    }
}



function initToCounter() {
  "use strict";

  if ($j('.counter.type1').length) {
    $j('.counter.type1').each(function() {

      var delay = $j(this).data('delay');
      var time = 0;

      if (delay !== "" && delay !== 0) {
        time = delay;
      }

      var $this = $j(this);

      if ($j('.touch .no_delay').length) {
        $this.parent().css('opacity', '1');
        var $max = parseFloat($this.text());
        $this.countTo({
          from: 0,
          to: $max,
          speed: 1500,
          refreshInterval: 50
        });
        resizeFonts();
      } else {
        $this.appear(function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $this.parent().css('opacity', '1');
            var $max = parseFloat($this.text());
            $this.countTo({
              from: 0,
              to: $max,
              speed: 1500,
              refreshInterval: 50
            });
            resizeFonts();
          }, time);
        }, {
          accX: 0,
          accY: -200
        });
      }

    });
  }
}
```

---

```
/*
 * jQuery.appear
 * https://github.com/bas2k/jquery.appear/
 * http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Michael Hixson
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Alexander Brovikov
 * Licensed under the MIT license (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */
(function($) {
    $.fn.appear = function(fn, options) {

        var settings = $.extend({

            //arbitrary data to pass to fn
            data: undefined,

            //call fn only on the first appear?
            one: true,

            // X & Y accuracy
            accX: 0,
            accY: 0

        }, options);

        return this.each(function() {

            var t = $(this);

            //whether the element is currently visible
            t.appeared = false;

            if (!fn) {

                //trigger the custom event
                t.trigger('appear', settings.data);
                return;
            }

            var w = $(window);

            //fires the appear event when appropriate
            var check = function() {

                //is the element hidden?
                if (!t.is(':visible')) {

                    //it became hidden
                    t.appeared = false;
                    return;
                }

                //is the element inside the visible window?
                var a = w.scrollLeft();
                var b = w.scrollTop();
                var o = t.offset();
                var x = o.left;
                var y = o.top;

                var ax = settings.accX;
                var ay = settings.accY;
                var th = t.height();
                var wh = w.height();
                var tw = t.width();
                var ww = w.width();

                if (y + th + ay >= b &&
                    y <= b + wh + ay &&
                    x + tw + ax >= a &&
                    x <= a + ww + ax) {

                    //trigger the custom event
                    if (!t.appeared) t.trigger('appear', settings.data);

                } else {

                    //it scrolled out of view
                    t.appeared = false;
                }
            };

            //create a modified fn with some additional logic
            var modifiedFn = function() {

                //mark the element as visible
                t.appeared = true;

                //is this supposed to happen only once?
                if (settings.one) {

                    //remove the check
                    w.unbind('scroll', check);
                    var i = $.inArray(check, $.fn.appear.checks);
                    if (i >= 0) $.fn.appear.checks.splice(i, 1);
                }

                //trigger the original fn
                fn.apply(this, arguments);
            };

            //bind the modified fn to the element
            if (settings.one) t.one('appear', settings.data, modifiedFn);
            else t.bind('appear', settings.data, modifiedFn);

            //check whenever the window scrolls
            w.scroll(check);

            //check whenever the dom changes
            $.fn.appear.checks.push(check);

            //check now
            (check)();
        });
    };

    //keep a queue of appearance checks
    $.extend($.fn.appear, {

        checks: [],
        timeout: null,

        //process the queue
        checkAll: function() {
            var length = $.fn.appear.checks.length;
            if (length > 0) while (length--) ($.fn.appear.checks[length])();
        },

        //check the queue asynchronously
        run: function() {
            if ($.fn.appear.timeout) clearTimeout($.fn.appear.timeout);
            $.fn.appear.timeout = setTimeout($.fn.appear.checkAll, 20);
        }
    });

    //run checks when these methods are called
    $.each(['append', 'prepend', 'after', 'before', 'attr',
        'removeAttr', 'addClass', 'removeClass', 'toggleClass',
        'remove', 'css', 'show', 'hide'], function(i, n) {
        var old = $.fn[n];
        if (old) {
            $.fn[n] = function() {
                var r = old.apply(this, arguments);
                $.fn.appear.run();
                return r;
            }
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Easy to see error thrown in console `$this.appear is not a function` ... we don't know what that should do. Did you forget to include a plugin function?

Comment: @charlietfl You're right.. added jquery.appear.js code to the javascript window and updated here as well.

Comment: It also seems that `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` causes problems with my `$(document).ready(function() {` calls, as I get this console error: `$ is not a function`

Comment: Yes it would.. if use noConflict need to do `$j(document).ready`

Comment: Maybe I will turn all `j`'s to `$`'s and see if this works better...  However this is not the main issue for why this won't work, is it?

Comment: @charlietfl nevermind, you fixed it indirectly!  The $j was part of it, the 2nd part was another missing function "countTo" - thanks!

Comment: You can use `$` inside document.ready if you do `$(document).ready(function($) {` The argument passes jQuery as `$` inside function